# The New Villa Acm solution strategy

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am trying to solve this ACM problem [The New Villa](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/3/321.html)

and i am not figuring out how to approach this problem definitely its graph problem but doors and the room that have switches to other rooms are very confusing to make a generic solution. Can some body help me in defining the strategy for this problem.
Also i want some discussion forum for ACM problems if you know any one then please share.

Thanks 
A.S

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a pathfinding problem on states.

You can represent each vertex with a binary vector of size `n`  + an indentifier - where which room you are in at the moment [`n` is the number of rooms].

`G=(V,E)` where `V = {all binary vectors of size n and a recored for which room you are in}` and `E = {(u,v) | you can switch from binary vector u to v by clicking a button in the room you are in, or move to adjacent lights on room }`

Now you only need to run a search algorithm on the possible paths.

**Possible search algorithms:**

1. [**BFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) - simplest to program, though slowest run time
2. [**bi - directional**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) BFS - since there is only one target node,
   a bi-directional search will work here, it is expected to be much
   faster then BFS
3. [**A***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) - find an [admissible heurstic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) and run
   informed A* on the problem. It is harder to program it then the rest - but if you find a good heurisitc, it will most likely perform much better.

(*) All of the above are both **complete** [will find a solution if one exists] and **optimal** [will find the shortest solution, if one exists]

(*) This solution runs in exponential time on the number of rooms, but it should end up for  `d <= 10` as indicated in the problem in reasonable time.